# Full width DropdownButton with adjust dropdown arrow icon in Flutter

Tags: dart, widget, flutter

I needed to add DropdownButton with full width with adjust dropdown arrow icon in Flutter as well. But with many tried it in many ways but it doesn't expand its width full.

This is my code for `DropdownButton`:

```
new Expanded(
    child: new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
        new DropdownButton(
            items: [
                new DropdownMenuItem(child: new Text("Abc")),
                new DropdownMenuItem(child: new Text("Xyz")),
            ],
            hint: new Text("Select City"),
            onChanged: null
          )
       ]
    ),
    flex: 1,
)
```

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Just adding `isExpanded:true` to the `DropdownButton`

```
  Widget example() {
    return DropdownButton(
          isExpanded: true,
            items: const [
               DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Abc")),
               DropdownMenuItem(child: Text("Xyz")),
            ],
            hint: const Text("Select City"),
            onChanged: null
        );
  }
```

Comment: Do not forget to add fix width container or expanded widget outside of DropDownButton widget otherwise "isExpanded: true" attribute will not work and show error in console. Thanks for asking query.

Comment: It makes sense, but I didn't test this variable because I assumed it meant the dropdown itself would be expanded/opened

Answer (score 3):

Try to add the following in the Column you have...

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  ...
)
```

You should not need the `Expanded` widget as that would try to fill the vertical space and not the horizontal (width) space.

Comment: Thanks @aqwert using your code i got full width of DropdownButton but DropDownButton Arrow not Adjusted there. As full width of DropdownButton arrow should be positioned at end.

Comment: Adding `isExpanded: true` to the `DropDownButton` fixed this @SandipPatel